# I have to check a number is palindrome or not by recursion

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
  int i,n;     
  printf("Enter the number");
  scanf("%d",&n);     
  i=pali(n);    
  if(n==i) 
    printf("Number is pall"); 
  else     
    printf("Not Pall");  
}  

int pali(int n) 
{   
  int r;  
  static sum=0;  
  if(n!=0) 
  {      
    r=n%10;    
    sum=sum*10+r;   
    pali(n/10);  
  }  
  return sum;
}
```

I used a static variable to add up the sum. Is there any way where no static variable will be used?

Comment: You could just pass sum as a second parameter. Is that cheating?

Comment: no i can't do that. this is the restriction for the program. i can pass only one parameter which is the input number

Comment: Do you need to handle numbers that when reversed are not representable as an `int`?  `1123456789` vs. `9876543211`  (too big for 32 bits.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the typical ("functional") approach is to carry the state in the form of a function argument. This often makes it necessary/nice to have a second function that does the actual recursion, which you can start by calling with the proper initial values for the state:

```
int do_pali(int sum, int n)
{
  if(n != 0)
  {
    const int r = n % 10;
    return do_pali(10 * sum + r, n / 10);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

the public function then just becomes:

```
int pali(int n)
{
  return do_pali(0, n);
}
```

In languages with inner functions this can be more neatly expressed (GCC supports this as an extension).

Comment: Worth mentioning that this also makes the working function tail-recursive. Thus increasing the likelihood of the compiler emitting a simple loop for the operation.

Comment: i can pass only one parameter in pali function and i can not use static function.

Comment: the function which perform recursion only have one parameter in function calling.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it this way :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int pali(int n)
{
  int sum = 0;
  int keeper = 0;
  for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 10) {
    if (keeper != 0) {
      sum *= 10;
      sum += (keeper - i * 10);
    }
    keeper = i;
  }
  sum *= 10;
  sum += keeper;
  return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int i, n;     
  printf("Enter the number : ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  i = pali(n);
  if(n == i) 
    printf("Number is palindrome"); 
  else     
    printf("Not Palindrome");  
}
```

Using recursion is even easier :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int pali(int n, int sum)
{
  sum += n - ((n / 10) * 10);
  n /= 10;
  if (n > 0)
    pali(n, sum * 10);
  else
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int i, n;     
  printf("Enter the number : ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  i = pali(n, 0);
  if(n == i) 
    printf("Number is palindrome"); 
  else     
    printf("Not Palindrome");  
}
```

And a recursive version with only one parameter :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int pali(int n)
{
  int fUnit, lUnit;
  fUnit = n;
  int mul = 1;
  while (fUnit > 10) {
    fUnit /= 10;
    mul *= 10;
  }

  lUnit = n - ((n / 10) * 10);
  n -= (fUnit * mul);
  n /= 10;

  if (mul == 1) return 1;
  else if (fUnit == lUnit) return pali(n);
  else return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int n;     
  printf("Enter the number : ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  if(pali(n) == 1) 
    printf("Number is palindrome"); 
  else     
    printf("Not Palindrome");  
}
```

Comment: i think it is not a recursion program. because you used a for loop to make the digits apart to reverse the number but you have to use recursion technique in which a function call itself untill the condition will remains true

Comment: @ShivamGoel I added recursion version, I thought the "or not by recursion" in the title was "not using recursion", better reading twice next time :)

Comment: i can't pass another variable as sum in recursion function. there is only one parameter in function call which is input number

Comment: @ShivamGoel I'll edit with this new restriction then :)

Comment: i know you edit it but you pass a second parameter in pali function ( int pali(int n, int sum) ) which is not allowed you can pass only one parameter

Comment: @ShivamGoel That's why I used the future tense "I'll", meaning now it's done :) (With my third edit)

Comment: No problem :) I hope the last version resolves your problem !

Comment: I don't think it's possible to find a recursive function with one parameter and no static variable. For the multiplication by 10 you need a static counter or the depth of recursion. Without static or a 2nd parameter, you can't get this information.

Comment: great. its working but it is a little bit complex .But Thanks.

Comment: but it is possible. i search a program where someone use math_function( log10 and pow ) to write that program

Answer (score 0):

Since your function returns `sum` you could replace this line:

```
pali(n/10);
```

with

```
sum=pali(n/10);
```

You'd also have to move it up a line too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimized version that

- Doesn't use local `static`.
- Only includes stdio.h
- Uses recursion.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void perform_useless_recursion (int n)
{
  if(n--)
  {
    perform_useless_recursion(n);
  }
}

_Bool is_pali (int n)
{
  perform_useless_recursion(1);

  int sum = 0;
  for(int i=n; i!=0; i/=10)
  {
    sum = sum*10 + i%10;
  }
  return n == sum;
}

int main (void)
{
  int n=5005;

  if(is_pali(n)) 
    printf("Number is pall"); 
  else     
    printf("Not Pall");  

  return 0;  
}
```

The code could be improved even further by removing the `perform_useless_recursion()` function.

The advantage of this code is that the actual calculation is performed by a fast loop, instead of slow, dangerous recursion. In the real world outside artificial school assignments, there is no reason to write inefficient and dangerous code when you could write efficient and safe code. As a bonus, removing recursion also gives far more readable code.

If you benchmark this code you'll notice that it will be faster than all other versions posted and consumes less memory.

Comment: i have enough time and enough memory to make my program run. it doesn't matter of some few bytes or few milliseconds

Comment: i just want to make a program in different ways so that i can improve my logical ability.

Comment: "perform_useless_recursion" > Not sure it would be accepted in a exam where you have to use recursion, but nice trick :)

Comment: @ShivamGoel Practicing recursion is mostly harmful, because the real world uses for it are so very few. You are better off spending your time on other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that check only the first and the last digits of the number and pass the rest of the number onward.

To explain better, think about the following cases:

- pali(**1**22**0**) would check for the first (**1**) and last (**0**) digits. Since 1 != 0 pali would return false.
- pali(1**789**1) would check first (1) and last (1). Since they're equal then the function would recursively return pali(**789**) (which itself would return false since 7 != 9).
- pali(**878**) would check that 8=8 and recursively return pali(**7**)
- pali(**3**) would check that first (**3**) and last (**3**) numbers are equal and return 0.

The challenge here is to develop an algorithm that:

- Check if first and last numbers are the same (even if it's only one digit!)
- Strip the number from first and last digits and call itself on the remainder

Then all you need to do is apply recursion. Here's a sample implementation:

```
int pali(int number)
{
    int smallDigit, bigDigit;

    /* When recursion ends suceffuly*/
    if (number == 0)
        return 1;

    /* Check for first and last digit of a number */
    smallDigit = number % 10;
    bigDigit = number;

    while(bigDigit/10!=0)
    {
        bigDigit = bigDigit/10;
        smallDigit = smallDigit*10;
    }

    /* Check to see if both digits are equal (Note: you can't use smallDigit here because it's been multiplied by 10 a few times) */
    if (bigDigit != number%10)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        number = (number - smallDigit)/10; /* This is why smallDigit was multiplied by 10 a few times */
        return pali(number); /* Recursion time */
    }
}
```